# mapFragment.getMap () is null when the user do a device screen rotation

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I created an android application which :

- display a google map
- retrieve the user geo localization and zoom the map in this geo loc
- retrieve a JSON via a web service and create some markers

The application works when the user access to it for the first time.

But when he rotate his device screen/when he changes the orientation,
the map can't be initialized.

In my onResume method I initialized the mapFragment and if it's not equals to null, I do a getMap() in order to intialize my GoogleMap map attribute.

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

...

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    if(googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if(mapFragment != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "mapFragment initialized");
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error during mapFragment initialization");
        }
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        if(map != null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "map initialized");
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "error during map initialization");
        }

    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "end of onResume");
}
```

When the user access to the activity, it's working:

```
12-17 09:35:02.306  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onCreate
12-17 09:35:03.746  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ end of onCreate
12-17 09:35:03.748  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onResume
12-17 09:35:03.759  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ mapFragment initialized
12-17 09:35:03.760  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ map initialized
12-17 09:35:03.760  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ end of onResume
12-17 09:35:03.844  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onConnected
12-17 09:35:03.848  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ google play services available
12-17 09:35:03.850  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ setUpMapIfNeeded
12-17 09:35:03.850  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ we have a map
12-17 09:35:03.865  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ setUpMap
12-17 09:35:03.866  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ location: Location[mProvider=fused,mTime=1418805217845,mLatitude=43.6137752,mLongitude=1.4302528,mHasAltitude=false,mAltitude=0.0,mHasSpeed=false,mSpeed=0.0,mHasBearing=false,mBearing=0.0,mHasAccuracy=true,mAccuracy=52.5,mExtras=null]
12-17 09:35:03.867  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ we retrieve markers thx to the web service
```

But when he rotate the device screen:

```
12-17 09:35:25.118  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onSaveInstanceState
12-17 09:35:25.119  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ end of onSaveInstanceState
12-17 09:35:25.260  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onCreate
12-17 09:35:25.427  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ lat et lng: lat/lng: (43.613774948887695,1.4302530884742737)
12-17 09:35:25.428  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ zoom: 13.0
12-17 09:35:25.430  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ markers retrieved
12-17 09:35:25.462  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ end of onCreate
12-17 09:35:25.470  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onResume
12-17 09:35:25.609  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ mapFragment initialized
12-17 09:35:25.609  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ error during map initialization
12-17 09:35:25.609  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ end of onResume
12-17 09:35:25.732  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onConnected
12-17 09:35:25.735  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ google play services available
12-17 09:35:25.736  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ setUpMapIfNeeded
12-17 09:36:28.522  25099-25099/com.xxx.xx D/LogMe﹕ onSaveInstanceState
```

The map can't be initialized.

Have you an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Shouln't you be using [getMapAsync](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html#getMapAsync%28com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback%29)? The `getMap` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try get the map in this way:

```
 protected void onResume() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            // Do markers
            return;
        }
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }
 }
```

Also, a sample project called `hello-map` [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android). It shows no problem for the `map rotation.`

Comment: Hi?

I have tried this solution before to create the stackoverflow question and I was the same problem.

Thanks

My solution was to create a classe RetainMapFragment and it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using XML to build the mapView/SupportMapFragment. Use a FrameLayout, do a replace with a new instance of SupportMapFragment. You can do more with it(add on ChildFragmentManager and more...).

```
private MapView mMapView;
private SupportMapFragment mSupportMapFragment;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    createMapFragmentIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void createMapFragmentIfNeeded() {

    mFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {

        mSupportMapFragment = createMapFragment();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map_view, mSupportMapFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
}

public void  setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null && mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        mMap = mSupportMapFragment.getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            //Setup map
        }
    }
}

protected SupportMapFragment createMapFragment() {
    try {
        return SupportMapFragment.class.newInstance();
    } catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: In my project I don't want to use a fragment but thanks for this answer :-).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue with a new class created RetainMapFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class RetainMapFragment extends MapFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

}
```

And I used this new class in my layout:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:layout_margin="5px"
    class="com.xxx.xxx.RetainMapFragment"/>
```